# Jasper report:blank docx format

Tags: jasper-reports, docx

Jasper report generating blank docx format if there are more than 25 columns and it works fine for pdf format

is there any way to work around this issue??

Comment: Looks like the page's width is too large

Comment: MS Word has limit for maximum supported page width

Comment: @Jeet - Please share the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting default A4 size in JRXML template file as `pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842"`

For example;

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              name="contact_information" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="100" leftMargin="0"
              rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="5b43d207-b777-4d0f-9834-f49baae34f14">
```